# Cat 5e wiring Type A incompatibility with Type B

Tags: troubleshooting, layer1, cabling, cable, utp

I am not an engineer but I’m having problems with my small network in my business. I have 11 computers after 13 yrs am having major problems. My network keeps shutting down, and my dental software on my server keeps crashing. My question is that I think my original installer of my low voltage used Type A to connect to the patch panel since the orange and green sets of wires are flipped. Does this matter. The patch cords I buy are over the counter at frys and I assume those are B type. Would this be affecting my network slowdown and crashing? It was ok for the first 10 yrs every once and a while shutting down, but now that we have added more computer thruout the years, it freezes at least 3x a day. I have a network gigibit adapter. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can hire, for a couple of hours, a certified installer with a tester (the very expensive kind of tester, in the price neighborhood of some of your dental equipment) to test and correct any cable problems. Freezing can also be a symptom of computer or application trouble, too.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: A-type or B-type cables don't matter as long as both sides of a cable are the same

Long answer: Although there are T568A and T568B terminated cables, both types can be used interchangeably. The difference is in color code only - the important detail is that the pairs match which can be taken for granted with retail cables.

The only actual difference is when one end of a cable is terminated in T568A order and the other in T568B order - this is a crossover cable that used to be necessary for switch-to-switch or computer-to-computer connections with early 10 and 100 Mbit/s equipment up to ca. 1999. Later devices usually support Auto MDI-X which makes crossover cables unnecessary.

For the problem at hand and assuming the trouble started once gigabit speeds where used, you can try the following:

1. check error counters on network interfaces and on the switch, look for collisions, FCS error, runts, jabbers
2. have your structured cabling checked; with gigabit speed, flawed termination or damaged cables can cause problems even when the cables worked fine with 100 Mbit/s
3. configure problematic links down to 100 Mbit/s - try (in preferred order)

   1. auto-100 on the switch (leaves autonegotiation active)
   2. 100 MBit/s full-duplex on both sides (only when this is possible on both the switch and the computer's network interface)
   3. 100 Mbit/s half-duplex (only with a non-managed switch)

Answer (score 1):

Agreed with Zac67.  If you connect a cable that has T568A on both ends with a cable that has T568B at both ends, the result is that its still a straight through cable. In other words, pins 1-8 will be pins 1-8 at the other end, in the respective order.  After you have checked all the cabling Zac67 have suggested, the next step is to go over server maintenance tasks -- check for old hardware that's breaking. And then if you know your hardware is fine, ask your software vendor if your practice (number of dental photos, etc) outgrown the software.

Comment: Good point - I actually lost focus after pointing out the potential cable issues.